# Last price from FUTURES market on Binance API with Python

Tags: python, binance

I am using the API endpoint https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol= to get last price info for markets, but I need the data for the FUTURES market, as sometimes there can be a big spread between the spot and futures last price.

How can I get this data point?

Using binance-python lib and python 3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For people who want to use [binance-futures-connector-python](https://github.com/binance/binance-futures-connector-python) to get the latest price of a symbol, you may use the following code.

```
from binance.um_futures import UMFutures

um_futures_client = UMFutures()
print(um_futures_client.ticker_price("BTCUSDT")) # returns something like {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '22774.80', 'time': 1674457064454}
```

Comment: Hi ! What is the time format this ? Can I use it to set up time counter ? Thanks !

Comment: The time format is call "Unix time". You can tools like https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert it to a more readable format. The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT)

Answer (score 2):

Use this endpoint to get the last price of the Pair in the futures market https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=<SYMBOL_NAME>.

Example:

https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBUSDT

Check this documentation [link](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics) for more information

Comment: Thanks man. You give us link in easy way. Otherwise, this link not in Documentation.